# Shutdown circuit of an EV gokart

Tags: batteries, relay, dc, contactor, electric-vehicle

My student project team is planning to build an EV gokart. It's supposed to have a shutdown circuit/kill switches. I was planning to implement a DC contactor/high power relay to connect/disconnect the battery.

However, in the data-sheets of most high-power relays and contactors, the values provided are for AC or max. switching current/voltage.

For example, for the KG TECHNOLOGIES [K100A-10-024B024-R](https://in.element14.com/kg-technologies/k100a-10-024b024-r/relay-spst-no-277vac-100a/dp/1295026) DC contactor it says in the [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1750397.pdf) that the max. switching current is 100 A. Can it be used for a 100 A DC current? There is no such rating provided in the datasheet.

[image: Picture of the data-sheet rating]

I'm also not sure if using a relay/contactor for this job is a good option or not. Can a MOSFET with high current rating be used for the same? The only reason stopping me looking into MOSFETs is their power loss that will happen during normal operation.

Comment: What is the voltage of the cart?  What is the current?  your contacter may not be adequate

Comment: Try looking for "solenoid relay" parts used in golf carts. Some are rated up to 300A and are designed for DC.

Answer (score 2):

No, breaking DC current is a different matter. It may work with the AC rated one you list, but you can't count on it unless explicitly stated in the datasheet or if you have done the qualifications yourself.

You need a DC rated relay rated for at least the peak voltage and current you may expect.

Answer (score 2):

When opening a contact, it will arc.

AC current goes to zero twice per period, which extinguishes the arc quickly.

DC current does not go to zero, so [the arc will continue to burn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zez2r1RPpWY) and destroy the relay or breaker.

Usually, high current DC relays/breakers have special measures to extinguish the arc. It can be a magnet that bends the arc away from the contacts, for example.

Basically, you need your contactor to be rated for the DC voltage and current you'll be using. Otherwise it will most likely burst into [flames](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-xInEewI_U&t=110s) at the first use.